# andengine compileReleaseNdk error

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio, andengine

I want to use andengine in my android studio project but I have ndk error while building.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':andEngine:compileReleaseNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    D:\Android\android-ndk-r9d\ndk-build.cmd NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\Android\workspace\simpleclock\simple_clock_as\andEngine\build\intermediates\ndk\release\Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-19 NDK_OUT=D:\Android\workspace\simpleclock\simple_clock_as\andEngine\build\intermediates\ndk\release\obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\Android\workspace\simpleclock\simple_clock_as\andEngine\build\intermediates\ndk\release\lib APP_ABI=all
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    D:/Android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: D:\Android\workspace\simpleclock\simple_clock_as\andEngine\build\intermediates\ndk\release\obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/andengine_shared/D_\Android\workspace\simpleclock\simple_clock_as\andEngine\src\main\jni\src\GLES20Fix.o: in function Java_org_andengine_opengl_GLES20Fix_glVertexAttribPointer:GLES20Fix.c(.text.Java_org_andengine_opengl_GLES20Fix_glVertexAttribPointer+0x40): error: undefined reference to 'glVertexAttribPointer'
    D:/Android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: D:\Android\workspace\simpleclock\simple_clock_as\andEngine\build\intermediates\ndk\release\obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/andengine_shared/D_\Android\workspace\simpleclock\simple_clock_as\andEngine\src\main\jni\src\GLES20Fix.o: in function Java_org_andengine_opengl_GLES20Fix_glDrawElements:GLES20Fix.c(.text.Java_org_andengine_opengl_GLES20Fix_glDrawElements+0x30): error: undefined reference to 'glDrawElements'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make.exe: *** [D:\Android\workspace\simpleclock\simple_clock_as\andEngine\build\intermediates\ndk\release\obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libandengine_shared.so] Error 1
```

I suppose I'm missing some OpenGL files?

Answer (score 3):

The Android Gradle plugin's NDK task does not actually use any Android.mk file that you may have provided in your jni/ folder. This was a great source of confusion for me until I figured that out.

It generates a intermediate Android.mk file during the build, based on parameters that you have set in your Gradle build script and on the content of your jni/ folder.

You can see this for yourself by inspecting the source for its NdkCompile task at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/55aebda607efcc29b8d9d5e1a99d446e320ff288/build-system/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/tasks/NdkCompile.groovy.

Note the `writeMakeFile(...)` method on line 126.

This is why the error you are getting from the ndk-build command that runs as part of your Gradle build references the build script `APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\Android\workspace\simpleclock\simple_clock_as\andEngine\build\intermediates\ndk\release\Android.mk`, not something like `APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\Android\workspace\simpleclock\simple_clock_as\andEngine\src\main\jni\Android.mk` as you might expect and want it to.

There is no way of getting the Android Gradle plugin's NDK task to use your own Android.mk file (believe me if there was I would have found it!).

You have two options for getting your NDK code compiling as part of Gradle:

1. Figure out the correct configuration to put in your build.gradle so that the generated Android.mk file contains the required `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv2` line and any of the other lines from https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/jni/Android.mk that are required.
2. Write a custom NDK compile task that uses the AndEnginge's Android.mk file directly. I've recently had to do this myself for an NDK source set that requires more parameters than the Android Gradle plugin currently supports passing via Gradle, so it if comes to this I can provide help.

I think in this case option 1 is open and so of course the preferable solution.

Something like this added to the android defaultConfig block should work:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            moduleName "myNDKModule"
            stl "stlport_shared"
            ldLibs "lGLESv2"
            cFlags "-Werror"
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I am very much *not* a C/native code expert (I know practically nothing) so cannot guess whether AndEngine needs `LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME` and `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` to be set to build correctly. *If* it does, you'll need to go with approach 2 (at least until if/when the Android Gradle NDK task supports configuring them). Though I have just checked out the AndEngine git repo and successfully run `ndk-build` after having removed them from its Android.mk file, which is promising.

(I found which NDK properties can be parametrised via inspection of https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/55aebda607efcc29b8d9d5e1a99d446e320ff288/build-system/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/dsl/NdkConfigDsl.java).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, there are new errors.. If you can help, please look at the log: http://pastebin.com/4xUWP93D

Comment: It should be `ldLibs "GLESv2"` instead of `ldLibs "lGLESv2"`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-rYK2oh8oo helped me to fix the build issues. Basically, you need to download (and extract) NDK from here: http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html and specify the NDK location in Module Settings. Also, you need to alter the andEngine's build.gradle file to include

```
    sourceSets{
        main{
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just adding the sourceSets to andEngine's build.gradle did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

Android.mk actually includes the line?

https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/jni/Android.mk#L10

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv2
```

These errors indicate it.

```
error: undefined reference to 'glVertexAttribPointer'
error: undefined reference to 'glDrawElements'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I checked it out and found that my `Android.mk` already contains this line