# Error while compiling andengine project

Tags: android, andengine

I tried to create a simple game project using andEngine and Android studio

I have downloaded the andEngine source, android NDK and configured the project. However, while compiling I'm getting following error

```
E:\Android\GameTest\andEngine\src\main\jni\src\GLES20Fix.c
Error:(9) undefined reference to `glVertexAttribPointer'
Error:(13) undefined reference to `glDrawElements'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [E:\Android\GameTest\andEngine\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/libandengine_shared.so] Error 1
```

It seems like I'm missing something.

I have changed the default location of NDK to 
D:\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10d

I need guidance on how to what exactly this means and what steps should I follow to successfully compile a project which reference andEngine.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding `ldLibs "GLESv2"` to the defaultConfig block of the andEngine build.gradle.

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 8

    ndk {
        moduleName "andengine_shared"
        ldLibs "GLESv2"
    }
}
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563243/andengine-compilereleasendk-error)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compile the NDK source, you can use the built-in compiled jniLibs.

See my answer here:

[ExceptionInInitializerError Physics World](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750746/exceptionininitializererror-physics-world/28752626#28752626)